# Make touch area for UIPanGestureRecognizer bigger?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to a custom `UIView` subclass, and this works as expected.

However the client now requests that the view should be easier to grab, is there a way I can make the gesture trigger from a bigger area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way to achieve something like this is to place the view inside a container view that is the "touchable" size. It can be set to have a clear color background so it won't be visible.

Have the pan gesture added to the container and it can have whatever size you want it to have.

Another way would be to not have a pan gesture on the view but to intercept the `touchesBegan` on the super view and work out if the touch is inside the required "touchable" area of the view you want to pan.